# Golang GlobalSign mgo Query in MapReduce

Tags: mongodb, go, mapreduce, mgo

```
import "github.com/globalsign/mgo"

job := &mgo.MapReduce{
    Map:    "function() { emit(this.name, 1) }",
    Reduce: "function(key, values) { return Array.sum(values) }",
    Out:    "res",

}

_, err = c.Find(nil).MapReduce(job, nil)
```

How to add 'query' to the above golang mgo mapreduce ?

Ref:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/
https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo#MapReduce

Comment: `c.Find(query).MapReduce...`

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg , Tested, working, Please post as answer,Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MapReduce` is a function of the Query struct returned by Find. So in order to apply your MapReduce to a query result, simply add a query document to the find function:

```
c.Find(query).MapReduce(job,result)
```

Answer (score 3):

Managed to get this done with MongoDb official godriver

```
"go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
"go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
"go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"

par := bson.D{
    {"mapreduce", "audit"},
    {"map", " function() { emit( this.name , 1 ); }"},
    {"reduce", "function(key, arr) { return Array.sum(arr); }"},
    {"out", "mr3"},
    {"query", bson.D{{"status", "SUCCESS"}}},
}

sr := db.RunCommand(nil, par)
```